# I cant set useState to an array of objects ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, async.js

I want to get the data of the anonymous user from firestore database then keep them in a `useState` to update the users' account with the data after the user logs in so I have done this :

```
   User && db.collection("users").doc(User.uid).collection("basket")
  .get()
  .then((docs) => {
   let array = [];
   docs.forEach((doc) => {
   array.push(doc.data()) })
   setTempBasket(array)
   console.log(TempBasket)  })
```

but when trying to console log the result as shown above it always returns undefined I have tried to to this :

```
   User && db.collection("users").doc(User.uid).collection("basket")
  .get()
  .then((docs) => {
    let array = [];
    let quantityPromises = [];
    docs.forEach((doc) => {
     
      quantityPromises.push(db.collection("users").doc(User.uid).collection("basket").get())
     });
     Promise.all(quantityPromises).then((allDocumentsFromForLoop) => {
      allDocumentsFromForLoop.map((documents) => {
        documents.forEach(async doc => {
            array.push(doc.data()) })})
           
                      
     })
     setTempBasket(array)
     console.log(TempBasket)  })
```

but I could not solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar situation and this is my solution. You'd better use async/await.
Don't forget to add **async** before the call of the function.

```
const result = await db.collection("users").doc(User.uid).collection("basket").get();
const result_array = [];
results.docs.forEach((doc)=>{
  result_array.push(doc.data());
});
setTempBasket(result_array);
console.log(result_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing there is you are trying to use the state variable right after you call the set callback function.

The call to the setTempBasket function will cause an update of the value of tempBasket and force an update with a new render call, but in the current render call, the value of tempBasket will be the same as the value that triggered the update.

On the next render call the value of tempBasket will be the one that was passed to setTempBasket.

You can see the behavior in the console of this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqhx71tc/)

```
function Example() {
  
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(null);
    console.log('render', count)
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => {
      setCount(count + 1)
      console.log('click', count)
      }}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
  
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```